# delete a row from a listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have three textviews and a button in each row of my listview , on button click i want to remove the paticular row from the listview. I have tried many codes but without any success. Please do help.Thanks in advance!!!

```
VivzAdapter adapter=new VivzAdapter(this,foodname,quantity,amount);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2,
   int position, long id) {
  int itemPosition     = position;}
}); 

}

}
class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
String[] t;
String[] u;
String[] d;
Context context;

VivzAdapter(Context c,String[] foodname,String [] quantity,String[] amount)

{

    super(c,R.layout.listviewcustom,R.id.tv1,foodname);
    this.context=c;
    this.t=foodname;
    this.u=quantity;
    this.d=amount;



}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)       context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewcustom,parent,false);
    TextView t1=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView t2=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    TextView t3=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
     Button b=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }


        });

    t1.setText(t[position]);
    t2.setText(u[position]);
    t3.setText(d[position]);



    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see where you are actually trying to delete anything. Please post those codes and what does/doesn't happen including errors.

Comment: I have a button b on click of it i want to delete a row from the listview i tried adapter.remove but did'nt work!!!

Comment: remove items from your arrays and then redraw your listview with notifyDataSetChange method

Comment: like this VivzAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); Farrokh??

Comment: @codeMagic u need to scroll a bit!!!

Comment: Scroll to your empty `onClick()`?

Comment: @codeMagic i tried many codes but not to my success pls do suggest!!!

Comment: Since you are inside the anonymous class, you will probably need ` VivzAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Why don't you use ArrayList  instead of three different String Array.

Comment: What you have to do here is, on onItemClick get the position, and remove data at this position from all the string arrays, and then call adapter>notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
 final int listItemPosition = position;
 Button b=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    foodname.remove(listItemPosition);
    VivzAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    });
```

note that you can delete just foodname because that just passed to super constructor, I think you should
declare objects and send that object to arraylist, like this :

```
class object {
String foodname;
String quantity;
String amount;
}
```

and use that like this

```
VivzAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<object>){

}
```

hope help you!!!

Comment: @user3755062: Did you have any problems getting your button to work on the very first row?? I am doing something similar to you but cannot get buttons to work on my top row. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179222/android-imagebutton-in-listview-row-clicklistener-not-responding/25179714?noredirect=1#comment39235096_25179714